# How to solve this integral involving an ugly root in the denominator

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I came across a crazy integration question involving polynomials

I tried making a substitution like ${\sqrt(x+1)}=t$ with a (good) intention as algebraic calculations could be easier without roots and umm ... ended up no where like this[image]

So I would be grateful if someone could advise on how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If steps so far good, finish putting integrand as a fraction of two polymomials [now there are still fractions made of other fractions and terms]. Then try partial fractions.

Comment: Hint: your last integral has the from $\int f(t+t^{-1}) \frac{dt}{t}$, you can use identity $\frac{dt}{t} = \frac{d(t - t^{-1})}{t + t^{-1}}$ to simplify it to one over $u = t - t^{-1}$.

Comment: Before proceeding, correct the mistake. It should be 
$I=\int \frac{1+t^2}{1+t^2+t^4}dt = \int \frac{1+1/t^2}{1+1/t^2+t^2}dt$. Then, $I = \int \frac{d(t-1/t)}{(t-1/t)^2+3}
=\frac1{\sqrt3}\arctan\frac{t-1/t}{\sqrt3}$

Comment: @Quanto Beauty. Thanks man. So the the motivation behind taking $t^2$ as common is to make it a quadratic right?